# KNN Classifier build from scratch with numpy, what is wrong with the code?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, knn

Why my KNN Classifier build from scratch with numpy gives different results than the `sklearn.KNeighborsClassifier`? What is wrong with my code?

```
# create a function that computes euclidean distance and return the most common class label 
    # for given k.
    def k_neighbors(self, x):
        lengths = [self.euclidean_length(x, x_train) for x_train in self.X_training] 
        k_index = np.argsort(lengths)[: self.k] 
        k_nearest_labels = [self.y_training[i] for i in k_index] 
        counts = np.bincount(k_nearest_labels) 
        most_common_label = np.argmax(counts) 
        return most_common_label
```

```
# running KNN classifier with K=5 to fit the data and make predictions.
classifier1 = KNN_Classifier(k=5) 
classifier1.fit(X_training, y_training)
predicted1 = classifier1.predicting(X_test)
```

They both apparently do the same but I have different outcomes. Where is the bug in my code?

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

classifier2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, algorithm='brute', p=2)
classifier2.fit(X_training, y_training)
predicted2 = classifier2.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on `sklearn` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html), there are multiple reasons:

1. Distance metric: you are using Euclidean distance metric, while `sklearn` by default uses `minkowski` which in `X,Y` make differences
2. To find `k` nearest neighbours, `sklearn`, by default, choose one of the `kd_tree`, `BallTree` and `BruteForce` methods, however, in your `k_neighbours()` function, you use `BruteForce`.
3. Last but not least, `k` value in your test is `5`, while you're using `4` for `skleran` equivalent

Comment: Thanks man, that was helpful! Kind regards.

Comment: I changed the sklearn.KNeighborsClassifier parameters to match with what you said but still not the same results. You can see in the code above. Any other suggestions?